# Solving $ 6f_4(x) - 4f_6(x) = 2f_2(x) $, where $f_n(x) = \sin^n x + \cos^n x$

Tags: trigonometry

> Let $f_n(x) = \sin^nx + \cos^nx$. Then, I need to find the number of values of $x$ in $[0, \pi]$ for which this relation holds:
>
> $$ 6f_4(x) - 4f_6(x) = 2f_2(x) $$

How to do this?

I tried: Substituting $\sin^4x + \cos^4x = 1 - 2\sin^2x\cos^2x$ and $\sin^6x + \cos^6x = 1 - 3\sin^2x\cos^2x$, which vanishes.

But, if I preserve one variable, I get $\sin x = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two hints:

1) $f_2(x)$ has a well-known property.

2) Only even powers occur,
so everything can be written
in terms of 
only sin or only cos.

Comment: I am getting $ sin(x) =0 $

Comment: That's certainly a solution. Is it  only one?